# PHP rewrite url but keep anchor tags

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite a URL that contains an #anchor tag - and append that #anchor tag to the new url?

In my news php script, I check to make sure the request_uri matches the data I have stored the the MySQL database. If not, I send a 301 header and header location to the correct URL.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Grab the $sid and $url stored in the MySQL table and set it as $realurl
$realurl = "/$sid/$url/";

if ($uri != $realurl)
{
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header( "Location: $realurl" );
    exit;
}
```

This has been working great for me, but the problem is that I have recently added a comments php script to my news pages. Depending on what is being done, it could append #comments or #comment_form to the url.

Is there any way to modify the above code so if $url and $realurl does not match - header location to the $realurl + keep any #anchor tag that may have been present?

---

**Problem Solved** - not sure how or why it works, but all I ended up doing was changing :

```
if ($uri != $realurl)
```

to

```
if (stristr($uri, $realurl) === false)
```

If the $uri does not contain my $realurl, the url is rewritten and #anchor tag still remains.

Comment: Anchor tag may only be parsed on client side, so you may need JS for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try concatenating the anchor tag to the end of the URL?

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Grab the $sid and $url stored in the MySQL table and set it as $realurl
$realurl = "/$sid/$url/";

if ($uri != $realurl)
{
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header( "Location: $realurl".#someanchortag);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: No, because depending on what is being done, the comment script  could append #comments or #comment_form

Comment: Can you post the comments script?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem - (the comments script was to big to post here anyways).